# Wordpress host IP changed

Tags: php, wordpress

I've got a Wordpress site on our home intranet that has run into trouble now that the IP address has changed - The index page loads, but not the CSS and I can't log in to the site administration panel.

Unfortunately I am a bit behind on backups. Is there a way to get Wordpress to refer to the new IP address?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You have two places to update this (well three, but we'll stick with the two).

***If*** you can still log into your admin section, type the following for your URI /wp-admin/options.php - so for example, if your site is http://localhost then your full URL will be http://localhost/wp-admin/options.php. Once you've logged into your site you should see two fields (well you'll see a lot of fields), but you'll want to look for the two with URL's in them - the Site URL and the Blog URL (in WP 2.7 the fields are labeled "home" and "siteurl", not sure on the other versions).

Or, you can log into MySQL database and run the following.

```
Select * from wp_options where option_name IN('siteurl','home');
```

I just ran this today on one of my installs. If you're option_value is set to your localhost - you can then run the following:

```
update wp_options set option_value='http://www.yourblogname.com' where option_name = 'siteurl';
update wp_options set option_value='http://www.yourblogname.com' where option_name = 'home';
```

This should update your table structure.

Comment: this solution is about changing domain names where the question is about IPs. What to do when the name remains the same and there is a full server migration, including DN ?

Comment: The answer provided a solution that ultimately fixed the issue. If your question is not answered, perhaps create a new question with further detail of what you're running into and comment with a link to that question in this thread.

Comment: I'm not sure what option_id 39 was in 2009, but I had to change option_id 1 and 36, though changing 1 got me into wp-admin where I could fix the other problems

Comment: Brandon - I've noticed it actually changes on various versions of WP, sometimes it's 39, I've seen 40, 36, & 37 before too.

Comment: You can't rely on the option_id you have to use WHERE `option_name` IN ('siteurl', 'home') as Binny V A says below

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for this. Saved me a lot of heartburn!

Comment: Use `where option_name = 'siteurl' OR option_name = 'home';` instead

Answer (score 11):

You have to change the 'home' and 'siteurl' in the settings. Since you cannot open the admin side of wordpress, open the database in phpMyAdmin(or something similar).

The options can be found in the 'wp_options' table(wp_ prefix might be different). Find the necessary setting using this query...

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_options` WHERE `option_name` IN ('siteurl', 'home')
```

Change the values of both the options to the new IP.

Answer (score 11):

To temporarily be able to login, use this code in your wp-config.php:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

or you can add this to your theme's functions.php:

```
update_option('siteurl','http://example.com/');
update_option('home','http://example.com/');
```

**Warning**: Updating the SQL database will be required in order for installed plugins to use the new URL/hostname. So if you use plugins modifying the database is required.

Comment: Thanks for this! Exactly what I was looking for. It's a lot more useful for those of us who keep changing networks and IP addresses.

Comment: I don't see a file called functions.php in the directory that has wp-config.php. Is there another name for the file which functions.php, or another directory I could find it in?

Comment: @AlexanderMcNulty functions.php will be in the root folder for your active theme

Comment: if you use `update_option` you'll want to remove it after it's run, it doesn't need to trigger every time, just once.

Comment: Defining the two option in `wp-config.php` only partially overwrite the siteurl and home options. This will allow to login without being redirected and change the article URLs but all plugins will still point to the old hostname so your CSS and JavaScript from plugins will fail. Update the SQL entries is totally required.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem once. Loginto your DB and check your wp_options (if wp_ is your table prefix) and then search for all records and replace your old ip with new.

Possible columns to have the old ip would be 'permalinks' etc.. Sorry I cant see my blog's table structure now otherwise I would have posted the correct column name.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem before when I was migrating a site from test to production. Conveniently, MySQL has a string replace function.

Try something like this:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content,"http://localhost","http://www.myblog.com")
```

Comment: Sorry, this is what you'd do to make all the links work... you need to fix your IP in the wp_options table to be able to login.  Try scouring Google, there are many posts telling you how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful for the link: https or http !!

in the command line:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

in the SQL, set new IP for xxxx

> mysql> use wordpress;
>
> mysql> select * from wp_options where option_id=1;
>
> mysql> update wp_options set option_value="http://xxxx" where
>   option_id=1;
>   exit

Restart server

Answer (score 1):

Possibly [WordPress.org's coverage of this issue](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL) was not available at the time the other answers here were written, but as of now I find it more complete and easier to follow.

In my case, the method of modifying `wp-config.php` was only partially successful.  The *Relocate method* described in the above web page ultimately succeeded.

Here is a synopsis of [WordPress.org's coverage](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL):

> ```
> 1 Changing the Site URL
>     1.1 Edit wp-config.php
>     1.2 Edit functions.php
>     1.3 Relocate method
>         1.3.1 Code function
>         1.3.2 Steps
>     1.4 Changing the URL directly in the database
> 2 Moving Sites
>     2.1 Altering Table Prefixes
>     2.2 Changing Template Files
>     2.3 Changing the Config file
>     2.4 Verify the Profile
>     2.5 Changing the .htaccess file
>     2.6 Additional items of note
>         2.6.1 Important GUID Note
>     2.7 Multi-site notes
>     2.8 wp-cli
> ```