# New web server instance is routing to old public IP

Tags: wordpress, apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I was working on a wordpress site hosted by apache2 on an ec2 instance. I recently had to stop my instance and restart it in order to resize the instance I am using.  However, when the new instance restarts, whenever I type the public IP address of the instance into my address bar, I get a connection timed out error.

The problem is that even though I am entering the new IP address (for example 5.6.7.8), the address that gets resolved is the old IP address (for example 1.2.3.4). In other words, even though I enter 5.6.7.8 in my address bar, the address automatically changes to 1.2.3.4, which no longer exists. Is there something related to ec2, apache2, or wordpress settings that I can change so it'll route to my new address?

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. Do you have the old IP address in your Apache config perhaps?

Comment: The machine is ubuntu so I checked the /etc/apache2/apache2.conf, but I don't see my old IP address. I'm sure the old IP address must be stored somewhere, but I'm not sure where it is.

Comment: this is probably in the wordpress config and/or dns

Answer (score 0):

this is probably in the wordpress config and/or dns

take a look at: [Wordpress host IP changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/535534/wordpress-host-ip-changed)

you probably need to update WP_HOME and WP_SITEURL