# Recommended to update my machine type. Can't access my WordPress site now

Tags: wordpress, cloud, google-compute-engine

I have a WordPress site setup in Google Cloud Compute. They recommended that I upgrade my machine type, so I did. After the update completed, I am no longer able to access my WordPress site. Any help?

I have a static IP and I already checked the firewall, but I wasn't sure what rules were there to begin with. It looks like everything for my site is being allowed. But again, not sure what was there to begin with

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things that might have changed when you span the new VM type.

1- The first one is the [external IP address](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/configure-instance-ip-addresses). Did you assign the same IP address to your VM? To do that the IP needed to be a static IP, otherwise it got lost when you deleted the original VM. If the new VM has a different IP, the applications running in the VM might need to be [reconfigured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/535534/wordpress-host-ip-changed). I would suggest taking a [Snapshot](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots) before doing any configuration changes.

You can always check if your VM is running and which IP is using from the Compute Engine section of your [Google Cloud Console](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/console).

2- The second thing to look into are your [firewall rules](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking). If your original VM had a tag allowing traffic and the new VM is not tagged, then the packets will be blocked.  I would suggest reviewing the rules to make sure they are still valid.

Comment: Hey Dan, this is what it goes to now:

The 104.199.121.4 page isn’t working

104.199.121.4 is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: I can establish connection to your HTTP(S) server on ports 80 and 443, which isolate the issue to WP. Looking at the WP error most of the forums point to [Theme and Plugin issues or .htaccess](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wordpress-is-currently-unable-to-handle-this-request/). There are two links that might help you to isolate the problem [1](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-the-internal-server-error-in-wordpress/) and [2](http://wpninjas.com/fixing-the-500-internal-server-error-in-wordpress/)

Comment: I try to access my VM on the Bitnami for Google Cloud, and it says I don't have any VM's???? All I did was upgrade machine type. Why would that delete my virtual machine? It says right in the docs that it will have no effect, and Google also recommended that I do this?

Comment: Although it still says that my instance is running in Google?

Comment: Please post the following links:
a) The documentation you followed to spin the original Wordpress VM 
b) The documentation you followed to upgrade the VM. 
c) In the previous steps did you use [Google Cloud Console](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-console/) or instead [Binami LaunchPad](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9AYB5Oq1kr0)? 

My understanding is that you can see the VM in your Google Project but not in your Bitnami LaunchPad, Is that right?